# Binding nested JSON to listbox in XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, data-binding, windows-phone-8

This is my modal,

```
 public class main
    {
        public List<categories> categorieslist { get; set; }
    }

    public class categories
    {
        public int categoryId { get; set; }
        public string categoryName { get; set; }
        public List<pdf> pdfdocs { get; set; }
        public List<video> videoFiles { get; set; }
    }

    public class pdf
    {
        public string URL { get; set; }
        public string language { get; set; }
        public string createdDate { get; set; }
        public bool isFavorite { get; set; }
        public bool isRead { get; set; }
    }
```

Im using JSON.NET to deserialize

```
 main mainobj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<main>(App.hello);
```

I need to display list of PDF's for a selected category,
Im using LINQ to filter that particular category, I am unable to bind the PDF list..

```
 pdf.ItemsSource = App.mainobj.categorieslist.Where(i => i.categoryId.Equals(s));

  <ListBox x:Name="pdf" Margin="0,0,0,363"  ItemsSource="{Binding}" Foreground="White">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding pdf.URL}" Foreground="White"></TextBlock>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
```

Comment: do you have objects in categories list?

Comment: mainobj is the only object I have created, its an instance of main class

Comment: what is mainobj.categorieslist? does it have items in it?

Comment: Ya it has items in it..list of categories , each item has categoryId,category name,listof pdf and list of videos

Comment: what do you want to bind to the listbox?

Comment: list of PDF's..Each category has list of PDF's ,I wanna bind the PDF URL to listbox..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding categorieslist}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding categoryId }" FontSize="20" />

                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding pdf}" Margin="0 20 0 0">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Border BorderBrush="Blue" BorderThickness="2">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding URL }" FontSize="20" />
                            </Border>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding videoFiles}" Margin="0 20 0 0">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="2">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding URL}" FontSize="20" />
                            </Border>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: I modified the answer! just check